# In Laravel/mySQL query, how to select users by comparing arrays (or how to incorporate array_diff in where clause)?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-collection, array-difference

**Qn in simpler terms:** I am searching as a user for other users. All users have set preferred languages and fluent languages. I need to select users whose fluent languages match with this user's preferred languages. Both fluent languages and preferred languages are array (text fields in DB but through JSON cast). How to do that? (Also, fluent language is just one of many conditions in the query. So the query structure itself cannot be modified now.)

**Details on what has been tried:** I am getting a list of users into `$users`. One of the conditions require me to compare `preferredLanguages` (This is an array->collection1) with `fluentLanguages` (This is also is an array->collection2). All values of `preferredLanguages` needs to be present in `fluentLanguage`. So, I am using `array_diff` and checking if the result is `null`.

The issue is how do I use this within the `where` clause? I can use `array_diff` in, say, an if condition, but I don't know to use it within the `where` clause.

I tried everything I can think of, but nothing works so far! Can someone please help?

```
$collection1=$preferrences->preferredLanguages;
$collection2='user_details.fluentLanguages';

$diff= array_diff($collection1, $collection1);

$users->where(function (Builder $query) use ($matchPref) {
        $query
           ->where($diff, '[]');  //I need to check if $diff is null/empty. I tried everything I can think of here. 
    });
```

**Edit:** I tried something else as siggested by Kenny below. I believe this might work but didnt quite solved it yet. Any help is appreciated.

```
$users->filter(function ($user, $key) use ($preferrences->preferredLanguages)){
            return ! array_diff($user['fluentLanguages'], $preferrences->preferredLanguages);
        });
```

I also tried with where but it did not work out as well.

```
$users->where(array_diff('user_details.fluentLanguages', $preferrences->preferredLanguages)->IsEmpty(), true)
```

Comment: Please, provide a clearer/simpler example or explain your case better. As things stand, your use case isn't very clear. Keep in mind that we don't know your full use case so maybe a simpler example with the same problematic could be helpful for us in order to help you with. Aside from that, I think that the `whereIn` clause is needed here somewhere.

Comment: Hi @KennyHorna, thanks. I added a simpler version. Let me know if that is helpful.

Comment: Also, another approach is what you might be suggesting. Traverse through all values in collection1 and for each value do a whereIn clause to compare with collection2. The issue is how to incorporate that into the query itself? I need to select only those users whose all values in collection1 contain in collection2.

Comment: in your `users` table, are you using a json column to store your `fluentLanguage`?

Comment: @KennyHorna, fluentLanguage is text in DB with JSON casting. I was thinking about whereJSONContains but did not make much progress there.

Answer (score 1):

One strategy that comes to my mind could be:

1. Get the `fluentLanguage`of each user.

```
$candidates = User::select('id', 'fluentLanguage')->get();
```

2. Filter them according to the condition.

```
$filtered = $candidates
                ->filter(function ($candidate, $key) use ($matchFluentIn) {
                    return ! array_diff($candidate['fluentLanguage'], $matchFluentIn);
                })
                ->pluck('id')
                ->all();
```

3. Get full details of these filetered list of users:

```
$users = User::whereIn('id', $filtered)->get();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The issue is the data is heavy with users running into tens of thousands. I believe this will be too heavy on the server. Also the query itself is much more complicated with many other conditions. Is there anyway we can add filter to the query? I believe I need to do some reading on this. Or any possibilities of doing something with the JSON which you might have been indicating above?

Comment: I tried something using the filter, but didn't quite work it out. Can you please check?